# $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ if $x \neq0$, $x \mapsto 0 $ if $x =0$

Tags: limits, functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x}& x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$

Is $f$ continuous at $0$? Does the limit exist at $0$?

Comment: What do you think yourself?

Comment: I would guess that the limit doesn't exist but I'm not sure, it also shouldn't be continous then but idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist because $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)=-\infty$. And $f$ cannot be continuous at $0$ because the limit does not exist.

Comment: Note that you have an unremovable discontinuity at 0. For example $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ has a removable discontinuity at 0 because the limit exists and you can redefine the function as the limit in 0 to make it continuous.